# Git checkout existing branch at tag

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm in a branch now and I am about to create a tag. Creating a tag will save the state of ALL of my branches correct? But later if I want to come back to this tag, how do I check it out with a specific branch? Because if I checkout a tag which contains state for all of my branches, how do I actually go to a specific branch within that tag? I don't want to create a NEW branch with

```
git checkout -b branch_name tag_name
```

I want to checkout an EXISTING branch on this tag when I come back to it later. I would imagine it would be something like

```
git checkout branch_name tag_name
```

but I can't find an example of that command anywhere.

Comment: "Creating a tag will save the state of ALL of my branches correct?" No, it's just a name attached to a single commit.

Comment: What matt said.  Tags are just labels/pointers to a single commit hash.  When you checkout a tag its the same thing as specifying a sha1 hash to checkout.

Comment: Ok, I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around this. So what is the correct way to go back to a tag, make a fix, then make a new tag based on that fix? For example, say I made a tag a month ago for version 1.2 of my app. I have since modified modified HEAD, but I want to go back to that tag, make a hotfix, then make a new tag to include the hotfix. When I go to the tag, then make the changes, then try to commit, it tells me I'm in a detached head state.

Comment: I think maybe I should go back to tag, branch from there, make changes, commit, tag.

Comment: Just read up on it http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-References#Tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722154/git-checkout-existing-branch-at-tag#comment34627934_22722154) and [Bauhaus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722154/git-checkout-existing-branch-at-tag#comment34627980_22722154) already noted in comments, a tag is just a name for an SHA-1.

But in fact, so is a branch!

When you do:

```
git checkout <sha-1>
```

git takes you "off" a branch and to a particular commit.  Git calls this a "detached HEAD".

If you name a commit SHA-1 by some other method, such as a tag or a "remote branch" (`origin/master` and the like), git does the same thing.

When you do:

```
git checkout branch_name
```

there is only one difference, but it's a very important one: git still checks out the SHA-1, just as with any other method, but it also puts you "on" the branch.

What this really means is that git writes the *name* of the branch into a file.<sup>1</sup>  That's what "being on a branch" means: that there's a file containing the name of the branch you are on.

Being "on a branch" mainly affects *new* commits.  Any new commit you make, git writes the commit into the repository, along with the commit-message, author, timestamp, parent commits, and so on.  Then, if you are "on a branch", git writes the new commit-ID into a file that keeps track of the tip of that branch.<sup>2</sup>  That causes the branch itself to point to the new commit.  Let's say, just for example, that the new commit has SHA-1 ID `c0ffee...`.  Git writes `c0ffee...` into the branch file.

Suppose you then `git checkout master` and get "on branch master".  Git switches to some other commit, on branch `master`.  Later, you want to come back and work more on branch `branch_name`, so you `git checkout branch_name` again.  Git does the same thing every time: it sees that this is a branch name, looks up the SHA-1 for `branch_name`, checks out commit `c0ffee...`, and then—because it's a branch name—updates the "which branch am I on" file.

If you now make *another* new commit, git writes the commit as usual, and writes the ID—let's say it happens to be SHA-1 `feedcab...`—into the branch file as usual.  So you're still "on branch `branch_name`", but now that means "commit `feedcab...`".

The key difference here between a tag and a branch is that a tag is not expected to move, and git won't update it with new SHA-1 IDs; but a branch *is* expected to move, and git will update it automatically.

---

<sup>1</sup>The file is `.git/HEAD` and after this it contains the string `ref: refs/heads/branch_name`.

<sup>2</sup>Specifically, `.git/refs/heads/branch_name` in this case.  However, git also has "packed" refs which are stored in other files.